# Can Apple block someone for updating?

Tags: macos

My friend violated Apple's NDA a while back with the beta of OS X Mavericks 10.9.4 Now he can't update.

He was stupid and now he freaks out because he can't update to the final version of OS X 10.9.4. Should he contact Apple? Or is it just his Mac? Like an server issue or something.

Comment: How does he try to update, and what happens when he tries? Has he tried downloading the update package and installing it with Installer? Theoretically, Apple could prevent a certain computer from updating, but I doubt that's what is going on.

Comment: Apple normally does not block somebody of violating the NDA - and they don't care about Betas, except you are Gizmodo or have not public hardware in your hands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is, he is using 10.9.4 - which is the newst OS Release.

1. Public BETA Release was the same as the Final one
2. He has a newer Seed Number or Same Build Number so he don't have to update

he can try the [Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1755?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) but on his own riskt. Make a Backup bevore.

And in the Other Answers are some huge misunderstandings:

- OS X 10.9 is and will be [FREE FOR ALL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567?mt=12&ls=1&v0=www-osx-upgrade-button)
- Apple Changed **nothing** for 10.9 user to Yosemite Servers
- there are now Public Betas for **everybody**
- Apple is still **seeding** beta updates for Mavericks

Answer (score -1):

I think according to your Mentions he is still using the Beta, and not a normal Version of Mavericks. I think apple doesn't seed any Updates for the Betas anymore. They have a new Beta OS now.

It could be that Betas have its own Appstore/Update Servers and Apple maybe lately have taken them down or changed to Yosemitte Servers.

If he was in the Beta Programm or downloaded the Beta from Dev Center (Free Download) he doesn't automatically get access to the Final release of Mavericks for free he has to buy Mavericks from the Appstore like every one else, then he can install the non Beta Mavericks and then get the Updates.

Comment: 10.9.x is free for everybody not to buy - Apple still seeding Betas for Mavericks (and will cont'd for Security) nothing changed to **Yosemite** - now are public betas available for everybody